# Infiniband SDP EGAIN error while using a TCP non-blockling socket

Tags: tcp, sdp, infiniband, ofed

I'm using Mellanox Connext-X 3 QDR cards on RHEL 6.2. I've OFED 1.5.4 because it includes SDP. I get EAGAIN error message when using SDP in LD_PRELOAD mode for a TCP app that configures  the socket in non-blocking mode. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what's supposed to happen. You asked it not to block, so it returned without blocking. You can understand `EAGAIN` to mean "You asked me not to block, but I cannot make forward progress without blocking. What would you like me to do?"

Comment: I don't get EAGAIN when I run on IPoIB. So what options to debug this. SDP log did not reveal much insight.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's exactly what's supposed to happen. Why is this a problem for you? If you want to block until the operation is possible, don't set the socket non-blocking. If you don't want to block because you want to do something else, then go do that something else. It is a fact of life that sometimes an operation cannot make further forward progress without blocking. What do you want to happen in that case?